# Regex Patern get no matches on PHP but works on regex101

Tags: php, regex

I need some help, I am having trouble with this script, i'm trying to get some data from a website so i made some a pattern

```
/<div class="panel-heading"><a href="(.+?)"\/><h5>(.+?)<\/h5><\/a><\/div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p><b> Author: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
    <p><b> Awarding University: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>
    <p><b> Level  : <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
    <p><b> Year: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
    <p><b> Holding Libraries: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>
<p><b> Subject Terms: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
    <b> Abstract: <\/b>(.*?)<\/p>
  <\/div>
<\/div>/su
```

And this works correctly on regex101 but when I put it on the php it wont return any matches

```
<?php
  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
  $myfile = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $filedata = fread($myfile,filesize("info.txt"));
  fclose($myfile);
  $re = '/<div class="panel-heading"><a href="(.+?)"\/><h5>(.+?)<\/h5><\/a><\/div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><b> Author: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
          <p><b> Awarding University: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>
          <p><b> Level  : <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
          <p><b> Year: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
          <p><b> Holding Libraries: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>
    <p><b> Subject Terms: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>
          <b> Abstract: <\/b>(.*?)<\/p>
        <\/div>
      <\/div>/su';
      preg_match_all($re, $filedata, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

      var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Any one can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's an example of the data i am trying to get

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><a href="url"/><h5>Title</h5></a></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p><b> Author: </b> author</p>
    <p><b> Awarding University: </b>  some stuff</p>
    <p><b> Level  : </b> PhD</p>
    <p><b> Year: </b> 0</p>
    <p><b> Holding Libraries: </b>  more stuff</p>
<p><b> Subject Terms: </b> other stuff</p>
    <b> Abstract: </b><p> Big text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have working solution:

```
  $filedata = '<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><a href="url"/><h5>Title</h5></a></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p><b> Author: </b> author</p>
    <p><b> Awarding University: </b>  some stuff</p>
    <p><b> Level  : </b> PhD</p>
    <p><b> Year: </b> 0</p>
    <p><b> Holding Libraries: </b>  more stuff</p>
<p><b> Subject Terms: </b> other stuff</p>
    <b> Abstract: </b><p> Big text here</p>
  </div>
</div>';

  $re = '/<div class="panel-heading"><a href="(.+?)"\/><h5>(.+?)<\/h5><\/a><\/div>'
          . '\s+<div class="panel-body">'
          . '\s+<p><b> Author: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<p><b> Awarding University: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<p><b> Level  : <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<p><b> Year: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<p><b> Holding Libraries: <\/b>  (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<p><b> Subject Terms: <\/b> (.+?)<\/p>'
          . '\s+<b> Abstract: <\/b>(.*?)<\/p>/msu';
  preg_match_all($re, $filedata, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

  var_dump($matches);
```

The problem was white space characters.

But I think that you should look at something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php which is much more powerful. Parsing html by regex can be tricky, use libraries for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly, I will definitely l look into what you sent mean while I have this working thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the whitespace-characters. I updated your regular expression to match all whitespace-chars like space, tab, line-break etc. You will notice the `\s*` to match all whitespace-chars in front of your needed data and the `.*` (maybe a bit floppy ;)) for any char like line-breaks tabs and other stuff.

```
$pattern = '/<div class="panel-heading">.*<a href="(.+?)"\/><h5>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/h5><\/a><\/div>.*<div class="panel-body">.*<p><b>\s*Author\s*:.*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<p><b>\s*Awarding University\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<p><b>\s*Level\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<p><b>\s*Year\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<p><b>\s*Holding Libraries\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<p><b>\s*Subject Terms\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.+?)<\/p>.*<b>\s*Abstract\s*:\s*<\/b>\s*(.*?)<\/p>.*<\/div>.*<\/div>/su';
```